# The result of comma expressions in D

Tags: compiler-errors, d

https://dlang.org/spec/expression.html says "Using the result of comma expressions isn't allowed". But the following D program compiles without errors with GDC 8.2.0:

```
void main() {
  int x, y;
  y = x++, y++;
}
```

Explain the discrepancy. Is it allowed or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spec change to forbid taking the result of a comma expression is recent.

For technical and political reasons, GDC is based on an older version of the reference compiler, which is several years old. D changes somewhat faster than Java, so this restriction isn't present in GDC.

Note that the D language version isn't strictly tied to the rest of the GNU compiler collection. To see the language version, you can use a test program:

```
import std.compiler;
import std.stdio;
void main()
{
  writeln(version_major, ".", version_minor);
}
```

Comment: Even the newest dmd doesn't throw the error! But since the spec says it, you shouldn't be using it anyway, since the error may be implemented at any time. (Or it might not, there's spec-defined errors that the compilers all allow and have for years, and then people say "we don't wanna break code" by correctly implementing it. Ugh.)